# Matplotlib save button not working in embedded Tkinter window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't seem to make the save button work in an embedded window. All other buttons have full functionality.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
pop = Tk()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(root.x, root.y)
ax.set(xlabel='Wavenumber', ylabel='Intensity', title=os.path.basename(root.filename))
ax.grid()

root.plot_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=pop)
root.plot_canvas.draw()

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(root.plot_canvas, pop)
toolbar.update()
root.plot_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)

pop.mainloop()
```

Comment: Look at the examples in the docs to see how to create the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`matplotlib` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) is followed correctly and save button works fine, but probably you are working in a restricted folder. If that's not the case, `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig` function would save the figure:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def save():
    plt.savefig('plot.png')

pop = Tk()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.arange(1,10,5), np.arange(1,10,5))

plot_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=pop)
plot_canvas.draw()

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(plot_canvas, pop)
toolbar.update()
plot_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)

b = Button(pop, text="SAVE", bg="red", fg = 'white', command=save)
b.pack()

pop.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14568) in matplotlib 3.1.0.

It will be fixed in matplotlib 3.1.1, which is to appear very soon hopefully.

In the meantime you can revert to matplotlib 3.0.3.

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately reverting to 3.0.3. did not solve the problem.

Comment: I can only test with 3.0.2 currently, and there it works fine.